# Unable to find out key values from nested list in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I am trying to find the owner login, owner key, license key, license name for all the repositories which were created_at or after ‘2013-06-04’ from the [https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos](https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos%E2%80%9D.).

This is using nested list but unable to find out the result: My code is given below:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos'

content = requests.get(url).content

j = json.loads(content)    
#print(j)

for each in j['owner']['license']:
    print (each ['login']['id'])
```

I am getting an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):File "<string>", line 11, in <module>
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Not sure how to resolve this issue to findout the key values and parameters. Need help for this.

Answer (score 2):

The structure of the response `j` is:

```
[
    {
        "owner": {
            "login": "something",
            "id": 12345
        }
        "license": None,
        "created_at": "2012-10-06T16:37:39Z"
    },
    {
        "owner": {
            "login": "another",
            "id": 6789
        }
        "license": None,
        "created_at": "2014-02-12T11:12:13Z"
    }
]
```

- Accessing `j['owner']` is incorrect because `j` is a list. What you want is the dictionary inside an item in the list such as `j[0]['owner']`.
- Accessing `j[0]['owner']['license']` is also incorrect because `"license"` is not a key of the `"owner"` dictionary. Instead, it is a key of the outer dictionary `j[0]['license']`.
- Accessing `each['login']['id']` is also incorrect because the field `"login"` is a string, not a dictionary. Instead it is another key in the same dictionary `j[0]['owner']['login']` alongside `j[0]['owner']['id']`.

With the structure I pasted above as reference, you can try this instead:

```
import json
import requests

url = 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos'
content = requests.get(url).content
j = json.loads(content)

for each in j:
    print(each["owner"]['login'], each['owner']['id'], each['license'], each["created_at"])
```

If you wish to filter the results by the `created_at` field:

```
for each in filter(lambda data: data["created_at"] >= "2013-06-04", j):
    print(each["owner"]['login'], each['owner']['id'], each['license'], each["created_at"])
```

Comment: How to filter it as created_at or after ‘2013-06-04’ ?

Comment: You can simply access the `each["created_at"]` field. I updated my answer to include it in the structure (for visualization) and also added a sample code for the filtering. Could you check if it works on your side?

Comment: Much appreciated. Thanks a ton

Answer (score 1):

`j` is an array, so you cannot access `owner` in it. I guess you'd want more something like:

```py
for each in j:
    ...
```

Edit:
You could even extract all the ids in a quite straightforward way:

```py
ids = [x['owner']['id'] for x in j]
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code `j` is `list` you need iterate over it like below:

```
import requests
import json
url = 'https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray/repos'

content = requests.get(url).content

j = json.loads(content)    

for i in j:
    print((i['owner']['id']))
```